# SQL Server database not getting updated

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am using the following code, but database is not getting updated:

```
Dim update As New SqlCommand("Update FAGR SET FAGRN=@FAGRN,FAGRU=@FAGRU WHERE FAGRC=@FAGRC", connection)

update.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FAGRC", SqlDbType.NChar, 3))
update.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FAGRN", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50))
update.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FAGRU", SqlDbType.NChar, 3))

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Do While i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    Try
        update.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).ToString
        update.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString
        update.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).ToString
        vartemp1 = update.ExecuteNonQuery()
        i=i+1

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Exception:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    Finally
        Me.Close()
    End Try
Loop
```

'IN A SIMILAR INSERT QUERY THE FIRST ROW OF GRID IS INSERTED IN DATABASE. THE OTHER RECORDS ARE NOT INSERTED BUT ALSO NO ERROR IS SHOWN.

Comment: please include the error exception in your question.

Comment: their is no error exception. The command runs smoothly but the database  is not updated with the changes made in datagridview

Comment: just check the `name` of your database from your `connectionString` and try to figure out if that was the correct database you're trying to update.

Comment: `i` is always zero in your code.  What is the value of `vartemp1`?  If it's > 0, then it worked, and the problem could be you are looking at the wrong database.  Happens a lot.

Comment: I just check your code. `if i = 0 then do while i < Rows.Count` it will loop forever.

Comment: vartemp1 is a variable to confirm if the changes are made in the database and show message accordingly.

Comment: The same connection string is being used to display the data effectively.

Comment: @spajce: the loop is running 1 time and then closed. Infact, i have created a temporary textbox to view the value of grid.rows.count and it is showing 1 while i make the changes in the grid.

Comment: try to use my answer. I believe my answer it might solve your problem :)

Comment: @larstexh: What u are saying is correct. the value of i was always 0. So if have added i=i+1  after the execute command. But still no success

Comment: Please avoid typing large chunks in **ALL CAPS** - this is very hard to read, and it's considering SHOUTING at people which is rude - don't do it - please fix your question - thank you

Comment: Apologies marc_s. for 1 caps statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you're referring to the right columns:

```
Dim fagrc As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns("FAGRC")
Dim fagrn As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns("FAGRN")
Dim fagru As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns("FAGRU")
```

`DataGridViewCell.ToString` do not return the cell value. From reflector:

```
Public MustInherit Class DataGridViewCell

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Concat(New String() {"DataGridViewCell { ColumnIndex=", Me.ColumnIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), ", RowIndex=", Me.RowIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), " }"})
    End Function

End Class
```

Do it like this:

```
Dim id As String = Nothing

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
        id = row.Cells(fagrc.Index).Value.ToString()
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("FAGRC missing.")
        Else
            update.Parameters(0).Value = id
            update.Parameters(1).Value = row.Cells(fagrn.Index).Value.ToString()
            update.Parameters(2).Value = row.Cells(fagru.Index).Value.ToString()
            If (update.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0) Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("Could not update FAGRC with value '" & id & "'.")
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @roger: Following error is showing in typing: 'Isnewrow' is not a member of 'system.windows.forms.datagridview'

Comment: @user3258190 Which `.net` version are you using? < 2.0? Because it IS a member of `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Error of row removed. But the initial issue still present

Comment: @user3258190 And how did the error suddenly disappear?

Comment: I don't have old source as i am trying to improve it constantly. I am sorry if i am bothering u much. But that's not my intention

Comment: It's hard to tell but I guess it's either the columns reference or the cell.ToString() which returns `{ColumnIndex=N, RowIndex=N}`, thus not matching `WHERE FAGRC=some value`.

Comment: I think i got it. I was filling the grid with adapter via datatable. and owing to auto grid filling the columns were not getting linked which u did by creating variables as columns . Pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yeah, then I guess the first problem was the indices. However, if this was correct, you still would have problem with the `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(N).ToString`.

Comment: Thanks again for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)

> 'IN A SIMILAR INSERT QUERY THE FIRST ROW OF GRID IS INSERTED IN
>   DATABASE. THE OTHER RECORDS ARE NOT INSERTED BUT ALSO NO ERROR IS
>   SHOWN.

```
 For Each dataGridViewRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
 If dataGridViewRow.Index = 0 Then 'hint: this is your temporary textbox
     Update.Parameters(0).Value = dataGridViewRow.Cells(0).ToString()
     'Others Stuff
     'vartemp1 = Update.ExecuteNonQuery()

     Exit For
 End If
```

Next

Hope it will helps.

Comment: an error is showing whil typing of: 'Cells' is not a member of 'System.Windows.forms.Datagridview'.

Comment: i just wonder. if that `Datagridview` you're using is from third party.

Comment: Created the following code but did'nt work:                        For Each datagridviewRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                If datagridviewRow.Index = 0 Then
                    update.Parameters(0).Value = datagridviewRow.Cells(0).ToString()
                    update.Parameters(1).Value = datagridviewRow.Cells(1).ToString()
                    update.Parameters(2).Value = datagridviewRow.Cells(2).ToString()
                    vartemp1 = update.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next

Comment: what is the error? i hope the error is not from your first comment.

Comment: No. the cell error is removed and the command runs smoothly. But the data is still not updated

Comment: then, try to check the value of `SqlParameter` if thats was the correct and try to check the value from that cell if exist from your database.

Comment: Can the issue be related to parameters sequence in command and then declaration? As the @FAGRC is used in where clause but declared first as it is the first column in my gridview

Comment: An update: I have added a variable row number to increase by +1 with every loop. and the value returned by execute command is greater then 0 as per the message. But when directly checked, the database is not updated

Comment: if that cell value for `FAGRC` was really equal or exist in your database. the data it should be updated.

Comment: The issue is resolved with use of the code by Roger. Thanks a lot for your support.